# I am getting an error that I do not understand when I try to knit documents on RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr

I am a relatively new R user. I've been knitting documents in the past using RStudio to create HTML and PDF outputs of my R files.

I have no idea what changed, but approximately 1 month ago I tried to knit a document and got the error portrayed in the picture. I am borderline-competent at R on my best days but otherwise have virtually no knowledge of anything "computer" or "coding" outside of what I've learned from DataCamp regarding R. I have been trying to figure out what happened so that I can continue knitting files, but legitimately do not understand.

I would be more than happy to provide any additional information/context that you need to help me solve this problem but, unfortunately, I just don't know where to start or what's required.

I know this is a bit of a bullshit question and I've tried to avoid asking about it for a while b/c I know I don't know enough to ask it correctly, but I'm at a point where I just want to start knitting again and I'll do whatever it takes to get back to that!

The things I've tried so far are:

1. Downloading and installing the newest version of R
2. Downloading and installing RStudio again
3. Downloading and installing MacTeX again
4. Trying random solutions from Stack Overflow that involve writing things in my "Terminal" (which I subsequently erase when they don't work).

I am using a MacBook Pro running macOS Catalina 10.15.7 for what it's worth.

[image: This is what I see on my RStudio when I attempt to knit]

I've copied and pasted the text of the error message below:

```
Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
  cannot open the connection
Calls: source -> file
In addition: Warning message:
In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
  cannot open file 'renv/activate.R': No such file or directory
Execution halted
```

Comment: That seems like an RStudio related problem. Try knitting directly from the R console, `knit("R Notes.Rmd")`

Comment: I tried running that in the Console and got the following error message: Error in knit("R Notes.Rmd") : could not find function "knit"

Comment: That's just because `knitr` isn't loaded. Try `knitr::knit("R Notes.Rmd")`. Also please try `rmarkdown::render("R Notes.Rmd")`.

Comment: You absolutely freaking ROCK—the second command was the one that helped me get the output that I wanted. I did a quick google search and found that the command could be altered to provide for PDF and HTML documents as follows: ``` rmarkdown::render("R Notes.Rmd", "html_document") ``` and ```rmarkdown::render("R Notes.Rmd", "pdf_document")````

Comment: Yeah - `render` I think will also detect the output type from your YAML header. I don't know what's going on, but I think the issue with with the RStudio `knit` button, so **you** can still knit, but RStudio can't for some reason. With this information you may be able to get help on the RStudio help forums.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and didn't want to run my Rmd files from the console, so there is the solution for using the button again (which I found [here](https://github.com/rstudio/renv/issues/981)):

```
> usethis::edit_r_profile()
* Modify 'C:/Users/User/Documents/.Rprofile'
* Restart R for changes to take effect
```

The output then shows you the path to your file. Just copy that path to the address bar in your explorer and choose the program you want to open it with. I chose the normal text editor. Delete "source('renv/activate.R.')" from this file, restart R, and everything should work fine again.